# WMQ JMS API SSL Sun JDK and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Tags: java, ibm-mq

How do I get a JMS Client using SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (in the queue connection factory) to connect to a server using  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

- Client Sun JDK 7 win
- Server IBM Power (i)
- MQ version 7.1 on the server
- MQ version 7.5.0.4 on the client
- Connections with MQ Explorer works fine
- the below code works with the ibm JDK C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ Explorer\jre\jre\bin
- the below code does not work with "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin with [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download installed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

Code:

```
       // Instantiate the initial context
        String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory";
        Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, initialContextUrl);
        Context context = new InitialDirContext(environment);
        System.out.println("Initial context found!");

        String keystoreName = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
        System.out.println("keystoreName " + keystoreName + " canRead " + new File(keystoreName).canRead());
        String truststoreName = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        System.out.println("truststoreName " + keystoreName + " canRead " + new File(truststoreName).canRead());


        // Lookup the connection factory
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = (JmsConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryFromJndi);


        System.out.println("CF = " + cf.getClass().getName());

        MQConnectionFactory mqcf = (MQConnectionFactory) cf;
        System.out.println("getSSLCipherSuite:" + mqcf.getSSLCipherSuite());
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());

        // Lookup the destination
        destination = (JmsDestination) context.lookup(destinationFromJndi);
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());

        // Create JMS objects
        connection = cf.createConnection();
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());

        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());

        // Start the connection

        connection.start();
        System.out.println("getSSLSocketFactory:" + mqcf.getSSLSocketFactory());
```

Gives me:

```
 Initial context found!
keystoreName C:/Users/...key.jks canRead true
truststoreName C:/Users/.../key.jks canRead true
CF = com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
getSSLCipherSuite:SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
getSSLSocketFactory:null
getSSLSocketFactory:null
keyStore is : C:/Users/.../key.jks
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : ibmwebspheremquserid
.....
  Valid from Mon May 14 23:59:46 CEST 2012 until Thu May 14 23:59:46 CEST 2015

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'qm' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'host(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
Inner exception(s):
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2393' ('MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR').
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'host(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA],3=host/host:1414 (10.20.28.12),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]],3=host(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure]
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA],3=host/host:1414 (10.20.28.12),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
FAILURE
```

Comment: do you have the option to make the client use TLS instead of SSL?

Comment: The client is using a JNDI queue factory, according to this link SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  is equvialent with TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SSL from the Oracle JVM (JSSE)

See also "[What TLS cipherspecs/ciphersuites are supported when connecting from Oracle Java (non-IBM JRE) to MQ queue manager?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/178651/what-tls-ciphersuites-are-supported-when-connectin/)"

In MQ Client version 8.0.0.2 there is a patch is included to use the TLS with Oracle JVM, this works with [lanes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25906529/203968) answer above

The get this to work you will need the latest MQ Client that contains 
[IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840): WMQ V7 JAVA/JMS: ADD SUPPORT FOR SELECTED TLS CIPHERSPECS WHEN 
RUNNING IN NON-IBM JAVA RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840
([download](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006037))

Depending on your location you may also need to install 
Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 ([download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html))

To use this you have to configured by using the JVM argument:

```
  -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
```

Note that the default security implementation behaviour [differs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270962) between Oracle and IBM JVMs :

The [Oracle JSSE Reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLContext) says:

> If the KeyManager[] parameter is null, then an empty KeyManager will
>   be defined for this context.

The [IBM JSSE Reference guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.security.component.doc%2Fsecurity-component%2Fjsse2Docs%2Fsslcontext.html) says:

> If the KeyManager[] paramater is null, the installed security
>   providers will be searched for the highest-priority implementation of
>   the KeyManagerFactory, from which an appropriate KeyManager will be
>   obtained.

Which means that you have to setup [your own ssl context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270918/203968)

```
SSLContext  sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
String  keyStore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
String  keyStoreType = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String  keyStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","");
KeyManager[]    kms = null;
if (keyStore != null)
{
    KeyManagerFactory   kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore    ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    if (keyStore != null && !keyStore.equals("NONE")) {
        fs = new FileInputStream(keyStore);
    ks.load(fs, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    if (fs != null)
        fs.close();
    char[]  password = null;
    if (keyStorePassword.length() > 0)
        password = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();
    kmf.init(ks,password);
    kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
}
sslcontext.init(kms,null,null);
```

And then supply that to the MQ JMS client:

```
    JmsConnectionFactory cf = ...                                                                     

    MQConnectionFactory mqcf = (MQConnectionFactory) cf;              
    mqcf.setSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
```

If using a application server this might be handled by your application server.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the IBM JRE/JDK and it will work.

Comment: This is windows...not supported anymore?

Comment: Yes. MQ Explorer uses the IBM JRE, so it is supported and it is what you should be using.