# Accessing Websphere MQ from a Notes Java agent

Tags: java, lotus-notes, ibm-mq

I want to access (Websphere) MQ via a Notes Java agent. The inspiration for my initial code I got from this article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-jms/

If I run my agent I get the 2009 message: "MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect Closure reason = 2009".

I have checked the connection via the MQ Explorer client and here I can access the channel and read messages.

I presume the connection via the Notes agent fails due to the fact it does not use the SSL key I got provided.

My question is how I should setup my Java agent, including the key file and use it in my code?

Anyone who can enlighten me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at the the code provided in the SO question "[WMQ JMS API SSL Sun JDK and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747283/wmq-jms-api-ssl-sun-jdk-and-ssl-rsa-with-aes-128-cbc-sha/35707030#35707030)".  The example provide should give you enough information on how to specify they key store details.  The question itself is regarding how to get it working with Oracle JRE, but given your question I would assume you are using IBM JRE and should not have the issues presented.

Comment: OK, I will take a look