# Configure SSL for IBM MQ v7.5

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ v7.5. I want to have mutual SSL authentication between queue manager and my JMS client.
I am a beginner in IBM MQ and SSL. Can someone help me step by step procedure for this ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Have a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692070/connecting-to-a-websphere-mq-in-java-with-ssl-keystore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Q&A on dwAnswers gives a step-by-step guide for versions older than 7.5 and also a link to the new runmqckm command in lieu of gsk6cmd.  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/180659/how-do-you-set-up-ssl-2-way-authentication-between/

Answer (score 1):

I think the redbooks are your friend in this  instance:

[Secure Messaging Scenarios with MQ](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg248069.pdf)

Specifically check out Chapter 11 - fine grained security.