# Multiple JSSE security Configuration

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq, jsse

I have one application which takes data from one IBM WMQ and send it to another... Queue which is upstream for me is recently SSL enabled.... However the downstream queue is still gonna be non secure one... For that I have made couple of changes which includes changes in the java.security file as well where I have included the IBM JSSE providers.. with these changes my upstream connectivity is established but my downstream connectivity has started failing... Error says something like JSSL Initialization error....

It looks to me that the changes that I have made to include the providers are compelling the downstream connection  to be secured as well...

Does anyone has any clue on what must have happening there...

I made changes as per below to make connection SSL Enabled:
[Connecting to a Websphere MQ in Java with SSL/Keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692070/connecting-to-a-websphere-mq-in-java-with-ssl-keystore/25906529#25906529)

And I am getting bellow error:

> [ERROR] Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '**********'
>   - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue
>   manager '******' with connection mode 'Client' and host name
>   '********'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001:
>   WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason
>   '2393' ('MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR').

Comment: You'll need to share exactly what you've done and what error you're seeing.

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: Please describe what changes you made rather than reference another question. Include code if you can.